# Linq Group by Sum Lists Elementwise

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-group

The list of doubles `SC` is of same size for all of `CTable`.
I would like add SC grouped by `CTable.Ch`. The result should be a List of sums. Is there an operator/customization for that?

```
Public Class SCRow
 Public L As String
 Public Ch As String
 Public SC As List(Of Double)
End Class

Dim CTable AS New List(Of SCRow)

Dim AggrC =
    From C In CTable
    Group C By Key = C.Ch
    Into Group
    Select New With
    {
       .Ch= Key,
       .SumSC = Group.Sum(Function(x)  ???)
    }

Example:

CTable.Add(New SCRow With {.L = "L1", .Ch = "Ch1", .SC = New List(Of Double)(New Double() {1.0, 2.0})})
CTable.Add(New SCRow With {.L = "L1", .Ch = "Ch2", .SC = New List(Of Double)(New Double() {3.0, 4.0})})
CTable.Add(New SCRow With {.L = "L2", .Ch = "Ch1", .SC = New List(Of Double)(New Double() {5.0, 6.0})})


Output:
Ch1 {6=1+5, 8=2+6}
Ch2 {3, 4}
```

Comment: Can you give a small sample of the output for a given input that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using Aggregate extension method along with Zip method. I have written the code in C#. Please translate it to VB.Net. Hope it will help.

**Aggregate:** Performs a specified operation to each element in a collection, while carrying the result forward.

**Zip:** The Zip extension method acts upon two collections. It processes each element in two series together.

```
public class SCRow
{
    public string L { get; set; }
    public string CH { get; set; }
    public List<double> SC { get; set; }
}
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var CTable = new List<SCRow>{
            new SCRow { L = "L1",  CH = "Ch1", SC = new List<double> { 1.0, 2.0}},
            new SCRow { L = "L1",  CH = "Ch2", SC = new List<double> { 3.0, 4.0}},
            new SCRow { L = "L2",  CH = "Ch1", SC = new List<double> { 5.0, 6.0}},
        };

        var result = CTable.GroupBy(c => c.CH)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Value = x.Aggregate((curr, next) => new SCRow
                {
                    CH = x.Key,
                    SC = curr.SC.Zip(next.SC, (n1, n2) => n1 + n2).ToList()
                })
            })
            .Select(y => new {
              CH = y.Value.CH,
              ScSum = y.Value.SC
            }).ToList();

    }
}
```

Comment: Dim AggrC =
            CTable.GroupBy(Function(c) c.Ch).[Select](Function(x) New With {
                Key .Value = x.Aggregate(Function(curr, [next]) New SC With
                {
                        .Ch = x.Key,
                        .SC = curr.SC.Zip([next].SC, Function(n1, n2) n1 + n2).ToList()
                })
            }).[Select](Function(y) New SC With {
                 .Ch = y.Value.Ch,
                 .SC = y.Value.SC,
                 .L = Nothing
            }).ToList()